# Node js is not connecting to my database using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-modules

Node js is not connecting to my database using mongoose giving me below error.

const err = new MongooseError(message);
MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

**Please note:** I have already connected to the mongodb server by using mongodin the terminal and I have also cd to the directory of my folder where the app.js is located on my pc before running the node app.js on the terminal

//Here is my code.

```
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
 
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB');
}
 
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
})
 
const Fruit = new mongoose.model ("Fruit", fruitSchema)
 
const fruit = new Fruit ({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Great!"
})
 
fruit.save() 
 
const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection
    const collection = db.collection('fruits');
    // Find some documents
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, fruits) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      console.log("Found the following records");
      console.log(fruits)
      callback(fruits);
    });
  }
`
```

`//I am trying` to connect Node js to my database using mongoose.

Comment: Is mongodb service in your system working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB')
```

First, replace localhost by 127.0.0.1 and if it doesn't work then check if your mongodb service is running or not in computer.
Go to task manager and switch to services tab and then locate mongodb and if it is stopped then start it.